# control a service from an activity

Tags: android, multithreading, android-service

I have a chat client activity which continously filtes incoming packets using a `while(true)` loop. On the basis of message contained in the packets, I need to start and stop a service. The service performs an intensive long running task. Since, the service starts in the same thread of the caller Activity, I cannot start the service and also continue to filter packets, otherwise it shows an ANR dialog. 
How can I keep both the activity and the service doing their tasks and also the activity to be able to later inform/stop the service?

I started the service in a new thread but that still gave an ANR.

**Edit**: Using *AsyncTask* and *BroadcastReceiver* works only if packet-filtering is stopped at the time of calling the service. Simultaneously doing both gives ANR.

Comment: you can start a service n continue to filter messages in activity using `Asynctask`, can you post logcat for ANR ? and also you can control service using a `public static` method in service or by sending a new action to start service.

Comment: @SIGSEGV: sorry, i am unable to generate logcat as of now... but using asynctask also gives ANR...

Comment: you hav to do all network operation in `asynctask`.

Comment: should i start the service in asynctask as well?

Comment: no no need, only netwokrk operations in AsyncTask

Answer (score 0):

Use a Broadcast Receiver and register with a particular intent-filter. Broadcast an intent whenever you need to do any processing based on the content of your chat messages. Within the receiver you could take whatever action you need to.

Comment: if i don't stop packet-filtering at the time of sending broadcast, ANR appears!

Comment: Maybe you could get the "Packet-filtering" to be done in a separate thread.

I'm not sure how exactly you have implemented your chat client. The ideal way would be to Asynchronously listen to the Socket connections and attach a callback to further process the received messages.